# Questions cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the main question list (main site and meta), I see this:

[image: screenshot]

The questions are cut off at some narrow width as if something is overlayed on top of them. I have seen this in Firefox 3.6.9 on a Mac 10.4 and on 3.6.10 on Linux. If I click "questions" then everything is correct. I do have the ability to run DOM inspector if there is any more useful info that I can provide.  But I can't seem to find which element is on top of the questions.

I was able to fix the problem in DOM inspector by deleting the overflow-x and overflow-y (!) CSS rules on the question-mini-list div. But I have no idea why that helps.

Comment: i'm looking into this. Thanks. btw are you using page zoom by any chance?

Comment: @Jin: This problem happens even if I manually reset the zoom and reload the page. But since you suggested it I tried also changing my font settings, and now I see that **does** eliminate the problem. If I change the minimum font size to a smaller minimum, then everything works fine. But if I increase the minimum font size, the questions get cut off like in the picture. I'm used to minor display glitches from having a minimum font size, but this is the first time I have seen such a significant change.

Comment: I see. thank you for the helpful info. I'll fix this asap. I've seen this glitch on FF4 before.

Comment: I also had this problem in Firefox 3.6.11 on Windows 7. I had to reduce the zoom amplification of the text.

Comment: I also have this problem in Firefox 3.6.12, in Ubuntu 8.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put in a fix. should be in the next deployment.

Comment: It seems to be fixed; will report if I notice it again.